# Return a List<E> of @OneToMany related entity in Criteria Select

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria

I have three classes as the following example:

```
@Entity
public class Book {

  @Id
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne
  private Author author;

  private String name;

  private LocalDate publishDate;

  private Long numberOfPages;

  // Getters and Setters
}

@Entity
public class Author {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String city;

    private LocalDate birthday;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Book> books;

    // Getters and Setters
}

public class BooksOfAuthor {

    private String authorName;
    private List<Book> books;

    public BooksOfAuthor(String authorName, List<Book> books) {
        this.authorName = authorName;
        this.books = books;
    }

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

BooksOfAuthor is a simplified representation of Author and Book. I'm trying to create a Criteria Select to populate this representation as following:

```
public List<BooksOfAuthor> simplifiedSelect() {
    CriteriaBuilder builder = manager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<BooksOfAuthor> criteria = builder.createQuery(BooksOfAuthor.class);
    Root<Author> root = criteria.from(Author.class);

    criteria.select(builder.construct(BooksOfAuthor.class, 
            root.get(Author_.name),
            root.get(Author_.books)));

    TypedQuery<BooksOfAuthor> query = manager.createQuery(criteria);

    return query.getResultList();
}
```

But this isn't working, I get the following error:

```
[dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
  [Request processing failed; nested exception is
    org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException:
      org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException:
        Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class
        [BooksOfAuthor]. Expected arguments are:
        String, java.util.Collection
        [select new BooksOfAuthor(generatedAlias0.name, generatedAlias0.books) from Author as generatedAlias0 where 1=1;
```

How can I properly do this select?

Comment: Have you tried with **public BooksOfAuthor(String authorName, Collection books)**

Comment: you cannot have a multi-valued field in the SELECT clause. See the JPA spec for JPQL BNF which shows valid JPQL

Comment: So, If I understood, there's no way to do this with Criteria? Just with JPQL? @BillyFrost

Comment: Criteria simply allows you to generate JPQL queries using an API; what is possible with JPQL is possible with Criteria. You CANNOT select MULTIVALUED fields ... in JPQL, or Criteria. Read the JPA spec

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this details about JPA Specs @BillyFrost. I decided do this with a List<Tuple>.